# CSS, HTML, Make div text remain on middle of its div regardless of text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text in the middle of the webpage inside a `div` tag, actually it is not yet on the middle, but I need it on the middle by default. There is a button there that when you click, the text in the middle will change. The problem is that, when I changed the text, it is not centered anymore. What I want is that, the text should always be at the center regardless of its text content.

```js
$("#myButton").on('click', function() {
  $('#throbber_status_info').html('TEXXXXXXXXXXXXXT');
});
```

```css
#throbber_status_info {
  position: absolute;
  color: black;
  top: 53%;
  left: 50%;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton">
  click me
</button>
<div id="throbber_status_info" style="">Text</div>
```

Comment: Do you really need it absolutely positioned?

Comment: Yes, I need it absolutely positioned

Comment: @Reymark Please be sure to review the linked duplicated - the accepted answer outline the exact CSS styles you need to center an absolutely-positioned element of variable width.

Comment: got it @Serlite, I will check it next time. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prefer not to have the `div` absolutely positioned but if you need it that way then try this:

```
#throbber_status_info {
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-color: #dadada;
  margin: 0px auto;
  top: 53%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wnqd85qr/3/) to see it in action.

Comment: Thank you, this is what I am looking for :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `text-align: center` property, it will automatically do that for you, see the updated snippet:

```js
$("#myButton").on('click', function() {
  $('#throbber_status_info').html('TEXXXXXXXXXXXXXT');
});
```

```css
#throbber_status_info {
  position:absolute;
  color:black;
  top:53%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="myButton">
  click me
</button>
<div id="throbber_status_info" style="">Text</div>
```

Comment: The aim is to vertically center the text too.

Comment: @KCarnaille You can use the `vertical-align:middle;` property then, it will do the trick

Comment: It only works with table layouts or display: inline-block properties. The purpose here is to center horizontally/vertically an absolute div !

Comment: thanks for this, but I need to retain the "top:53%" attribute here

Comment: @Reymark I updated the code to retain your requirement :)

Comment: Thanks @Tha'erAl-Ajlouni , this is what I am looking for :)

Comment: @Reymark You are welcome :) Kindly mark it as the right answer for future references

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display:flex;`

https://jsfiddle.net/wnqd85qr/1/

With Flexbox you can easy center vertical en horizontal. But you need a height in your CSS code or its not working.

Here you can learn more about flexbox:
http://flexboxfroggy.com/

Comment: thanks for this, :), Its a great help

Answer (score 1):

If you want to change the `left` property dynamically by using jQuery you can code:

```
$("#myButton").on('click', function() {
  $('#throbber_status_info').html('TEXXXXXXXXXXXXXT').css('left', function() {
    var tw = $(this).width();
    var w = $(this.parentNode).width();
    return (50 - (tw / 2 / w * 100)) + '%';
  });
});
```

of course, this is not the only option that you have and this approach is not responsive, i.e. the `left` property should be updated on resize event.

https://jsfiddle.net/Lommba8s/

Answer (score 1):

using Jquery you can create a function to center the text.

```
$("#myButton").on('click',function(){
    $('#throbber_status_info').html('TEXXXXXXXXXXXXXT');
  centerMe('#throbber_status_info');

});
function centerMe(JQ_Selector){
    var medItemWidth = $(JQ_Selector).width()/2;
  var medWindWidth = $(window).width()/2;
  $(JQ_Selector).css('left', (medWindWidth - medItemWidth) + 'px');
}
```

See JSFiddle here. https://jsfiddle.net/99s400nw

Comment: You **should never** center elements using JavaScript. It can work noticeably slower. What's more important, you'd need to recalculate appropriate positions **every time** size of the window changes!